# Remote Connection to EJB working on localhost but fails on 127.0.0.1 and another server

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, jndi, remote-access

I just learning ejb remote on wildfly 12 server. I have successfully connected to ejb in my the same computer with jboss-ejb-client.properties when accessing the same JVM with localhost (Working example) :

```
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port=8080
```

when I try to access the same ejb using 127.0.0.1 than localhost , it waits so long and nothing happens without displaying any erroe. Here is the  jboss-ejb-client.properties when accessing server on the same JVM with 127.0.0.1 (Failure example) :

```
 remote.connections=default
 remote.connection.default.host=127.0.0.1
 remote.connection.default.port=8080
```

I also  deploy the same ejb service to another computer with ip 192.168.1.101 and changed host and set password credientials accordingly and try to access but the same endless wait happen again. Here is the jboss-ejb-client.properties when accessing to another server at 192.168.1.101 (Failure example):

```
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=192.168.1.101
remote.connection.default.port=8080
remote.connection.default.username=username
remote.connection.default.password=**password
remote.connection.default.connect.timeout=3000
```

build.gradle is :

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec
api  group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction', name: 'jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec', version: '1.1.1.Final'
       // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb/jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec
    api group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb', name: 'jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec', version: '1.0.1.Final'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jboss-ejb-client
    api group: 'org.jboss', name: 'jboss-ejb-client', version: '4.0.10.Final'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.xnio/xnio-api
    api group: 'org.jboss.xnio', name: 'xnio-api', version: '3.6.3.Final'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.xnio/xnio-nio
    api group: 'org.jboss.xnio', name: 'xnio-nio', version: '3.6.3.Final'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.remoting/jboss-remoting
    api group: 'org.jboss.remoting', name: 'jboss-remoting', version: '5.0.7.Final'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.sasl/jboss-sasl
    api group: 'org.jboss.sasl', name: 'jboss-sasl', version: '1.0.5.Final'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.marshalling/jboss-marshalling-river
    api group: 'org.jboss.marshalling', name: 'jboss-marshalling-river', version: '2.0.5.Final'
```

And context lookup procedure :

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
Calculator calc = (Calculator) ic.lookup("ejb:/ejbtest-service-1.0/CalculatorService!com.testejb.model.Calculator");
```

Is there some thing missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend following this example project

https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/12.x/ejb-remote

The default mode us using local auth (which works on file permissions) where as the HTTP example uses true auth

This example shows how to use auth as well

https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/12.x/ejb-security/src/main/resources/wildfly-config.xml

Where as the first example (https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/12.x/ejb-remote/client/src/main/resources/META-INF/wildfly-config.xml) used

```
 <property key="wildfly.sasl.local-user.quiet-auth" value="true" />
```